# Distribution Derivative

Tags: distribution-theory

Question: Find the second derivative of the function $f(x) = e^{-|x|}$ using the sense of Theory of distribution.

My Attempt: 
$$
\left< f',\phi \right> = -\left< f,\phi' \right> = -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, \phi'(x) \, dx = 2 \, \phi(0) - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|x|} \, \phi(x) \, dx.
$$

Thus, $f'= 2\delta +h,$ where $h$ is the function $h(x) = e^{-|x|}.$ Now, by definition: $\left< f'', \phi \right> = - \left< f', \phi' \right>,$ but  $\phi' = \psi$ and apply the rule
$$\left< f',\psi \right> = - \left< f,\psi' \right>.$$

This gives:
$$\left< f'',\phi \right>  = \left< f,\phi'' \right>$$

By the preceding computation:
$$- \left< f,\phi' \right> = 2\phi'(0) - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|x|} \, dx$$

After integration by parts:
$$-2\phi'(0) + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, \phi(x) \, dx.$$

Thus, 
$$\left< f'', \phi \right> =-2\phi'(0)+ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, \phi(x) \, dx.$$

herefore, in the distribution sense,
$f'' = 2\delta+f,$
where, 
$\left< \delta', \phi \right> = \phi'(0).$

Is my work correct?

Comment: When you write TeX, put `$` or `$$` around every formula, but not around the text. Then it looks better and you won't have to use `\space` to get a space between words. Look at my edit to see how I have done.

Comment: Ok, I am learning LaTeX day by day.

Comment: Your first calculation is wrong. The two $\phi(0)$ cancel, but instead you will have a factor $\operatorname{sign}(x)$ under the integral.

Comment: Would you please write the correct solution for me. I am not with sign(x) function.

Answer (score 5):

$$\begin{align}
\langle f'', \phi \rangle
&= - \langle f', \phi' \rangle
= \langle f, \phi'' \rangle
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|x|} \, \phi''(x) \, dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{x} \, \phi''(x) \, dx
+ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \, \phi''(x) \, dx \\
&= \left( \left[e^{x} \, \phi'(x) \right]_{-\infty}^{0} - \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{x} \, \phi'(x) \, dx \right) 
+ \left( \left[ e^{-x} \, \phi'(x) \right]_{0}^{\infty} - \int_{0}^{\infty} (-e^{-x}) \, \phi'(x) \, dx \right) \\
&= - \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{x} \, \phi'(x) \, dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \, \phi'(x) \, dx \label{middle step}\tag{*} \\
&= - \left( \left[e^{x} \, \phi(x) \right]_{-\infty}^{0} - \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{x} \, \phi(x) \, dx \right)
+ \left( \left[ e^{-x} \, \phi(x) \right]_{0}^{\infty} - \int_{0}^{\infty} (-e^{-x}) \, \phi(x) \, dx \right) \\
&= -2 \, \phi(0) + \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{x} \, \phi(x) \, dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \, \phi(x) \, dx \\
&= \langle -2 \, \delta + f, \phi \rangle
\end{align}$$

**A parenthesis:**

Note that \eqref{middle step} can be written using $\operatorname{sign}$ as
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \operatorname{sign}(x) e^{-|x|} \, \phi'(x) \, dx
$$

Comment: great work. Now makes sense. I have one more problem to verify and make correction. Is there any way to send you a picture of my solution?

Comment: Why not put it in a new question?

Comment: Because of my knowledge of LaTeX :(

Comment: Give it a new try; you will learn.

Comment: it's full of mathematical terms and operations. I found your facebook, If you don't mind, may I knock you there?

Comment: You may, but I won't be able to answer there. I'm currently blocked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92406/discussion-between-tazim-taz-and-md2perpe).

Comment: It seems the minus sign got lost on the last step. Should be $f'' = f - 2 \delta$.

Comment: @Maxim. You're right. I fixed it.